# unlock local Cloud Foundry user. uaac?

Tags: cloud-foundry, unlock, cloudfoundry-uaa

Howto unlock local Cloud Foundry user. Didn't found an option on uaac Gem?

Our users use CI/CD tools with wrong passwords and then their CF users get locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `uaadb`

```
select * from sec_audit;
+--------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+
| principal_id                         | event_type | origin                     | event_data     | created             | identity_zone_id |
+--------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 10:51:47 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 11:46:34 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 11:46:47 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 11:46:56 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 11:47:01 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 12:51:47 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 13:46:34 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 13:46:47 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 13:46:56 | uaa              |
| e38af5c2-ae71-406e-bfd5-2df4f8891cf7 |          1 | remoteAddress=192.168.35.27 | admin-opr | 2015-11-11 13:47:01 | uaa              |
+--------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Truncate this table and all locks are away

Answer (score 1):

By default, UAA does not permanently lock accounts after failed attempts. It will cause an account to be unavailable for a period of time (5 mins default) and will continue to lock for 5 mins until a successful login occurs. If you have not changed the default configuration, just wait 5 mins and try with the correct credentials.